# Data Validation

Tags: validation

I'm using Wordpress as CMS and have a checkout page where info is inserted into the db using $wpdb->insert.  I have 2 questions:

1. Is 'sql injection' already a part of that function or do I need to add my own code?
2. Are there wordpress form input validation functions that I can use on my custom form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is 'sql injection' already a part of that function or do I need to add my own code?

When inserting input to the database you should use `prepare` method of WPDB class which supports both a `sprintf()` - like and `vsprintf()` -like syntax. [**read more at the codex**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks)

> Are there wordpress form input validation functions that I can use on my custom form?

Yes there are many and they are covered in [**Data Validation**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) codex entry like toscho pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

The Codex has a really good page about this topic: [Data Validation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation). There isn’t much to add. :)